# making axes distinct from other grid

Tags: matlab, graph, properties, distinct, axes

Does anyone know how to make x-axis and y-axis look a bit bolder or somehow distinct from other grids?
[image]

Somehow I want it to look like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stupidest thing I can think of is drawing a line with LineWidth = 2

> > figure();
> >     plot([0 0],[-200 200],'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0 0 0])
> >     hold on;plot([-200 200],[0 0],'LineWidth',2,'Color',[0 0 0])

Though it has some obvious disadvantages, like that it ends at some place.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only way to do it. I suppose that a better solution would override the resize callback and extend the axes when the limits are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`hline` and `vline`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039) from the MATLAB File Exchange. It will let you draw horizontal and vertical lines at any given point and extend those lines to infinity (so redoing axes will still keep the lines drawn all the away across your plot). If you need to draw to specific handles, [here's an advanced `hline`/`vline`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18796).

Comment: How do I extend those lines to infinity? I doubt that it is possible. I saw the command "x=get(gca,'xlim');" in "hline.m", and later on there is "plot" command, which as far as I know cannot do it.

Comment: But using "hline" and "vline" is better of course, than my solution (Clearer code)

Comment: @Andrey - okay, technically they don't extend to infinity, but resizing axes causes the lines to automatically resize to match the new axes. (I'm guessing the same kind of callback Nzbuu discussed is implemented)

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean.